# ¿A qué se refiere con "no se encontró el archivo de metadatos en C#"?

Tags: c#

[image: Error CS0006]
Estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto de C# en mi carpeta de GitHub y me sale el error de la imagen ¿Tendrá que ver con que empecé el proyecto con la versión 8.0.15.0 de MySQL y ahora tengo la versión 8.0.17.0?

```
Error   CS0006  No se encontró el archivo de metadatos 'C:\Users\Roberto Carlos\Documents\GitHub\Equipo5-6B\LoginSB\bin\Debug\LoginSB.exe'
```

Comment: Bienvenido Roberto... Por favor copia y pega el error. Esto ayudará a los interesados a visualizar mejor tus errores.. Date una vuelta por [ask] para más información

Comment: Intenta limpiar la solucion y volver a compilar.

Comment: A mi me ha pasado y el problema consistía en que tenía incompatibilidades entre las versiones del Framework: el proyecto WEB con la versión 4.5, mientras que un helper generador de PDFs con la versión 4.7.2.
Luego de igualar las versiones el problema se corrigió.
Saludos.